# Modify sub URL according to page URL while using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to find all the URLs of the web page `http://abc.ac.sk`using ***JSOUP*** library. But there are so many sub links with the same domain. As a example webpage of the library is `http://lib.abc.ac.sk` . Inside that page there are some sub urls stored as follows.

```
<ul class="ddmenu">
  <li class="dropdown"  ><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">About Us</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="aboutus/vission_mission.php?about">Vision & Mission</a></li>
       <li><a href="aboutus/librarians_message.php?about">Librarian's Message</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The **#** contains a link as `http://lib.abc.ac.sk`. I want to create the full url of *Vision and Mission* page as `http://lib.abc.ac.sk/aboutus/vission_mission.php?about`.

I've tried to concat the Base URL=`http://abc.ac.sk` with the sub url `aboutus/vission_mission.php?about` As follows.

```
public String FixURL(String BaseURL, String Link) {
    final String protocol = "http";
    String fullURL;
    if (!Link.toLowerCase().startsWith(protocol)) {
        fullURL = BaseURL + Link;
    } else {
        fullURL = Link;
    }
    return fullURL;
}
```

But this leads to wrong results as `http://abc.ac.sk/aboutus/vission_mission.php?about`.
I want to change the base URL as according to the changes of the domain.But I have no idea to how to find specific changes of the url. Guys I'think you can understand this situation.Is there any idea to fix this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `...select("a").absUrl("href");` gives you the absolute url of the link if that is what you need?!?

Comment: That is the solution which I was expected.I tried but I was unable to find it.Thank you @Eritrean.